# how to print whole array of object properties value in vanila js

Tags: javascript, html, css

just like angular *ngFor, I want to implement in vanila js and print whole array of object properties on one div

I have tried this but this doesn't work for me

```js
for(let skipques of arr){
    var elem = document.createElement("p");
    elem.setAttribute('Id',arr.ques);
    document.body.appendchild(elem);
}
```

```js
let arr = [
    {ques: 2},
    {ques: 5},
    {ques: 8},
    { ques: 10}
];

<div id="questId"></div>
```

I want to list all ques value on div because this array of object is dynamic

Answer (score 2):

```js
let arr = [
    {ques: 2},
    {ques: 5},
    {ques: 8},
    {ques: 10}
];

let questId = document.querySelector("#questId");
arr.forEach(e => {
    let p = document.createElement("p");
    p.setAttribute('Id',"quesId");
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(e.ques));
    questId.appendChild(p);
});

console.log(questId.innerHTML);

/*
result : 
<p id="quesId">2</p><p id="quesId">5</p><p id="quesId">8</p><p id="quesId">10</p>
*/
```

```html
<div id="questId"></div>
```

Comment: hi thanks for answer but I don't want to change id of div attribute i want  output like this <p id="quesId">2</p> , <p id="quesId">5</p> ...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
arr.forEach( item => {
    for(let prop in item) {
        console.log(item[prop]);
    }
});
```